# Query string in URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

So I've taken over a project a friend of mine had started but didn't have the time to finish. It's an online e-commerce system built with CodeIgniter. The problem is, every product's url is setup like `site.com/store/viewProduct?id=3` with the ID as the identifier. Now I am okay with keeping the ID in the URL, but I would like to make it so the `?` is removed and the product title is also added in as well. So the final URL would be like `site.com/store/viewProduct/3/cake-cutter` or something like that.

The controller functions all reference to `$_GET['id'];` as well. I know I will have to change that as well... but to what?

I tried changing the URLs to like shown above and then using `$this->uri->segment(1,0);` to get the product id, but I got an error.

I will use CodeIgniters built in `url_title();` function to generate the product names, but what is the easiest way to go about changing these urls?

Comment: you want to dynamically change them? like a redirect?

Comment: I guess I'm asking what would be the best way to do this with minimal effort. I don't really know how I can do this without going through and basically rewriting the entire shopping cart class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do would just be to change the way the controller is getting your ID. I am assuming you don't need the 4th URI segment and that is just for SEO/usability purposes... but even if you do, you will still get it with the way this function is set up.

```php
class Store extends CI_Controller {

    //site.com/store/viewProduct/3/cake-cutter
    public function viewProduct($id, $name)
    {
        //do stuff and now you have access to $id and $name
        //$id == 3
        //$name == 'cake-cutter'
    }

}
```